# Code for function "respondtosubmit"

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a google apps script and am having some trouble using the GUI builder. I have seen some examples but never got the code for what I've seen. The function I need is called respondtosubmit and I think it takes the form data and uses it as variables in the script. Can somebody help me find the code to create one that will take the data from a text field in the GUI and make it the variable ID?

Comment: This is covered on several of the official tutorials. Did you go through them?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, the GUI builder is deprecated, it was supposed to be sunset today, but a little repreive till 2nd October.  You should use UIApp or HTMLService.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service

Comment: Thank you but I still don't know how to have the GUI interact with the script.